# how works Role Hierarchy in salesforce

Tags: sharing, role-hierarchy

If I have three users A,B,C and A is superior then B then C.I created one custom object School__c.its owd is private.The user C has read/write permission.All are in same profile.role is different like A is CEO ,B is manager and C is Employee.
so,user A and B what kind of access will have??.

Comment: This sounds like a test question or an interview question. In both cases, giving you the answer would defeat the purpose of asking you this question. In any case, though, this is likely something that you'll find in the official Salesforce documentation, and/or on Trailhead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as Derek mentioned, this sounds like a test or interview question. In both cases, giving the answer would defeat the purpose of asking this question. In any case, though, this is likely something that the op will find in the official Salesforce documentation, and/or on Trailhead

Answer (score 1):

A will have access to records owned by B and c Whereas B will have access to records owned by c.

Remember, Access comes by various means in Salesforce.

Beyond setting the organization-wide sharing defaults for each object, you can specify whether users have access to the data owned by or shared with their subordinates in the hierarchy. For example, the role hierarchy automatically grants record access to users above the record owner in the hierarchy. By default, the Grant Access Using Hierarchies option is enabled for all objects, and it can only be changed for custom objects.

You can go through the below links where you can read more on Role Hierarchy in Salesforce:-

- [Create a Role Hierarchy](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/data_security/data_security_roles)
- [User Role Hierarchy](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_roles.htm&type=5)
- [Controlling Access Using Hierarchies](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_controlling_access_using_hierarchies.htm&type=5)